# How to disable Win+L in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

I am using a Linux VM in a Windows host, now some hotkeys conflicts.

I just want to disable Win+L, without disabling other hot keys.

Comment: why don't remap the VM shortcut?

Comment: I have this problem too. I'm on a physical mac where Cmd + L takes me to the browser URL but am in my Windows VM, locking myself at least 5 times a day.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To supplement Sébastien VALSEMEY's answer, actually there is a way to do that :)

1. go to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`, if there is no `System`, create one
2. create a 32bit DWORD, name it `DisableLockWorkstation`
3. set the value of `DisableLockWorkstation` to `1`
4. it will take effect immediately

[image: image here]

[**Registry tweak**](http://www.howtogeek.com/167579/how-to-make-your-own-windows-registry-hacks/):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"DisableLockWorkstation"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: This disables locking entirely, not just the hotkey. The option disappears from the Ctrl+Alt+Del menu and the `LockWorkStation()` API function no longer works

Comment: On my own computer, Ctrl+Alt+Del still works, and Win + L is disabled

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del still works, but "Lock Workstation" no longer appears in the menu because the ability is completely disabled

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no mean to disable only one Win+X keyboard shortcut.

What I can suggest is to disable completely Win+X hotkeys:

1. Type regedit in RUN or Start search box and press Enter. It'll open Registry Editor.
2. Now go to following key:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. In right-side pane, create a new DWORD `NoWinKeys` and set its value to 1

[image: NoWinKeys]

4. Close Registry Editor and restart your system. After reboot, all Win+X hotkeys will be turned off in your system.

To re-enable them, delete the DWORD NoWinKeys created in step 3.

Comment: This disables the other hotkeys, but doesn't seem to affect Win+L

Comment: Just wanted to add that if the `Policies/Explorer` key does not exist, you can create it.

Comment: I can confirm that this does not affect Win+L ...

Comment: I can only conclude that this is a conspiracy.

Answer (score 0):

Download a tool that allow you to remap Windows keys,

I suggest this one ---> [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/)

Remap Win+L to Nothing... or whatever you want... et voilá!!!

Comment: SharpKeys says it's never heard of the keycode generated by Win+L

Comment: sharpkeys is a tool to remap keys. A shortcut is not a key, it can't be remapped

Comment: You should test out what you suggest before posting it. Mod4+L is captured much lower before it gets to "SharpKeys"